# Як правильно: "хеш" чи "геш"

Tags: терміни, різниця-між-словами, запозичені-слова

Випадково знайшов у вікіпедії наступні статті:

[Геш-функція](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F)

[Геш-таблиця](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F)

Як правильно писати "хеш" чи "геш" (з точки зору українського правопису)? Та взагалі, звідки пішло слово "геш"?

Comment: Це невирішене питання українського правопису. Є багато прихильників передавати «h» як «г». І є багато прихильників передавати «h» як «х».

Comment: Не бачу в цьому сенсу, коли в нас є ґ. Така ситуація питоміша для сусідніх мов.

Comment: @Follower і я не бачу. А щодо прихильників: серед фахових лінґвістів набагато рідше зустрічаються прихильники хекання.

Comment: Але в звучанні `hash` мені щось ніяк не вдалося розчути `г`. Як тоді це може бути `геш`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наразі більшість джерел, здається, дають варіант «геш»:

- «Англійсько-український словник з математики та інформатики» 2010 року (Є. Мейнарович, М. Кратко): «[геш-таблиця](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F&dicts=2&highlight=on)»;
- Термінологічний портал Microsoft: [«геш», «геш-з’єднання», «геш-індекс», «геш-код», «геш-секціонування», «гешування», «геш-функція» тощо](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=hash&langID=uk-ua).

Хоча от трішки старіші [«Словники україни on-line»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) 2006 року пишуть: «хеш-адре́са», «хеш-адреса́ція», «хеши́рування» (sic!), «хеш-табли́ця», «хешува́ння», «хешува́ти», «хеш-фу́нкція».

І «геш», і «хеш»  — різні варіанти транслітерації англійського «hash». Походження англійського  «hash» — поза темою даного сайту (це, може, на [English Stack Exchange](http://english.stackexchange.com/)).